# Modern List Form to Open In a Dialog

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, modal-dialog

I know in the modern experience, the form for a new list item already opens in the same window as the list. I am curious if it is possible to have it open in a dialog box like the classic list experience.

I went to advanced settings, and selected yes to "Open Forms in Dialog", and it still pulls the form up on the side of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

Using out of the box functionalities of SharePoint, it is not possible to open the modern list forms in dialog like classic experience.

Comment: That is what I figured, but just wanted to get others input. Thank you for the reassurance